# What alternative use can I give to an internal graphic card?

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, hybrid-graphics

I have recently bought an nVidia Quadro FX1700 and as my PC has an onboard card (Intel 82Q965).

I was thus wondering what uses I could give to the card.

I have also read about the use of the dedicated card as GPU computing device but  I am not quite interested in using the DGP for anything but graphics.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: what do you mean by `besides the use as hybrid graphics` there are only two graphics cards, one is dedicated (nvidia, amd radeon) and other is integrated which comes with your computer's main processor (intel or amd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, the sky is the limit. Open CUDA is a rapidly developing community moving toward using the GPU for everything. It tends to center around graphics because that's one area that requires enormous processing, but there are many other uses, like math, parallel computing, cluster computing, and more.

https://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-accelerated-libraries